# RPi 4 Bluetooth not functioning

Tags: bluetooth

I reset my raspberry pi 4 and now the bluetooth isn't working. I have tried different devices to connect to but all of them will connect and then disconnect immediately after which in the bluetooth GUI will show as timed out. I already connected the devices that I am currently trying to connect and now they aren't working.

I am getting this error as of late:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-11-16 19:17:12 MST; 4 days ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 754 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─754 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --noplugin=sap

Nov 16 19:17:12 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Nov 16 19:17:12 raspberrypi bluetoothd[754]: Bluetooth daemon 5.50
Nov 16 19:17:12 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Nov 16 19:17:12 raspberrypi bluetoothd[754]: Starting SDP server
Nov 16 19:17:12 raspberrypi bluetoothd[754]: Excluding (cli) sap
Nov 16 19:17:12 raspberrypi bluetoothd[754]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14
Nov 16 19:17:12 raspberrypi bluetoothd[754]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.17 p
Nov 16 19:17:12 raspberrypi bluetoothd[754]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.17 p
Nov 16 19:17:12 raspberrypi bluetoothd[754]: Failed to set privacy: Rejected (0x
lines 1-19/19 (END)
```

Every time I try to connect to a device it will trust, pair, but will connect and then disconnect.

I have added --disabled=sap to the helper. I have made sure that rfkill isn't soft blocking. I have tried every variation of connection in bluetoothctl. I tried removing and reinstalling the bluetooth driver from apt. I tried installing pulse. I have even reinstalled the OS and made sure that I have the full OS and not lite. I have removed the devices

Comment: Are you using Raspberry PI OS Bookworm? Is it fully updated?

Comment: @CoderMike. I am on buster. and it's fully updated.

Comment: Why not use the latest OS?

Comment: @CoderMike I’ve read some stuff online that says it doesn’t work as well yet and that there is less community support for networking. They say overall that buster is better for beginners so I’ve just stuck with that since that’s also what my pi came with.

Comment: Don't now what you have been reading. Buster went end of life back in 2021. I suggest you get a spare sd card and try Bookworm.

Comment: @CoderMike I suppose at this point it couldn’t hurt.